# Scalatra does not mount new service

Tags: scala, scalatra

I am trying to mount the service to scalatra but after compiling and starting the app `GET /logging` is not recognized by scalatra

ScalatraBootstrap.scala

```
import org.scalatra._
import javax.servlet.ServletContext


class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override  def init(context: ServletContext): Unit = {
    context mount(new LoggingService, "/logging/*")
  }
}
```

LoggingService.scala

```
import org.scalatra._

class LoggingService extends ScalatraServlet {
  get("/*") {
    "hello"
  }
}
```

I get

```
Requesting "GET /logging/" on servlet "" but only have:
GET /
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will solve it.

```
get("/") {
   "hello"
}
```

---

```
context mount(new LoggingService, "/logging/*")
```

The "/logging/*" means that it will add all with prefix /logging/

---

Example

```
get("/") {
    "hello"
}

get("/1") {
    "hello1"
}

get("/2") {
    "hello2"
}
```

use with "/logging", "/logging/1" or "/logging/2"